# <path> attribute d: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected number (there is a number)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Looked at [this](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/15814-error-attribute-d-expected-number-m00c/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840416/error-path-attribute-d-expected-number-when-trying-to-build-a-line-chart-w), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811434/error-path-attribute-d-expected-number-mnan-nanlnan-nan) and a bunch of other similar posts, where the issue is clear, that there was a letter or some other NaN error in the path. However...

Getting the error `<path> attribute d: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected number, "…04,13.507 5.0004` on my `<path>`

The path is

```xml
<path 
    d="
        M31.9004,21.79
        L24.9004,29.79
        C24.6704,30.05 24.3494,30.2 24.0004,30.2
        C23.6504,30.2 23.3304,30.05 23.0994,29.79
        L16.0994,21.79
        C15.6604,21.29 15.7104,20.53 16.2104,20.1
        C16.7104,19.66 17.4694,19.71 17.9004,20.21
        L24.0004,27.18
        L30.0994,20.21
        C30.5304,19.71 31.2904,19.66 31.7904,20.1
        C32.2904,20.53 32.3394,21.29 31.9004,21.79
        M24.0004,5
        C13.5064,5 5.0004,13.507 5.0004
    "
    id="Color"
></path>`
```

which ends in `5.0004`

Could someone please explain why it thinks there is a letter and not a number at the end, which is throwing this error? Is it possible it doesn't like the `id` in the path tags? if so, why is the error only pointing to the `5.0004`?

Comment: A Bezier cubic curve, C needs 6 values: You have 5

Comment: Thanks for the eyes! Now, if I add the 6th value, it converts into a NaN. Any thoughts? I don't ever work with SVGs so this is beyond me @enxaneta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @enxaneta stated, I had a bezier curve that was missing a digit and throwing a NaN... i removed the whole curve as it wasnt needed.